# I get the error waiting for connection xdebug on netbeans on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

I have configured my file php.ini so:

the path is /etc/php5/apache/

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler= "dbpg" 
xdebug.remote_mode ="req"
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1 
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

In my info.php appears active

[img localhost/info.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85MB4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misspelled:

`xdebug.remote_handler= "dbpg"`

It should be **dbgp** (or rather, just remove the whole line).